# I don't understand how this simple javascript function works

Tags: javascript, function

index.html :

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="foo2.js"></script>
</head>

<script>
var foo2 = new foo2();
foo2.printThis = function (input){
   console.log("done");
}

</script>
</html>
```

foo2.js:

```
function foo2(){    
    this.printThis = function (input){
      console.log(input);
   }
}
```

I thought the way foo2 is supposed to be used is like this:

```
var foo2 = new foo2();
foo2.printThis("hello");
```

but in my index.html example, "foo2.printThis" is being equal to a new fucntion. What does this mean, what is it called, why would you re define a function like this and how do you use it? I have a Java background and this makes no sense to me.

Comment: Looks like an attempt at making a [custom object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript#Custom_objects).

Comment: Can I ask you where is the _body_ of your document?

Answer (score 1):

The script in `foo2.js` defines a constructor function, called `foo2`, which adds a method named `printThis` to its instances.

The incline script instantiates that constructor, and changes the value of the global variable `foo2` to be the instance instead of the constructor.

Then, it replaces the `printThis` method of the instance (defined in the constructor) with a slightly different method.

This doesn't make much sense, but you can do it, yes.

Comment: How does "input" gets passed on to the new foo2.printThis function in index.html ?

Comment: @DarkNight After replacing the `printThis` method, the new function completely ignores the passed arguments. You can still use `foo2.printThis("I am ignored")` if you want.

Comment: In my local example (which has more lines then what i provided), `input` is not being passed on to the newly created function anywhere in `index.html`. But  `foo2.printThis` has an output. How is `input` being passed on to it tho? that's my question.

Comment: @DarkNight `foo2.printThis` will always log `"done"`, it has no input.

Comment: Ok assume the function does take in an input and instead of printing `"done"` in outputs the input. At that point where is the input coming from?

Comment: @DarkNight The arguments are passed when you call the function.

Answer (score 0):

In index.html code actually overriding printThis for particular instance of foo2 object.

```
var foo2 = new foo2();
foo2.printThis = function (input){
   console.log(input +" I am in index");
}

foo2.printThis('test'); //print > test I am in index

var foo3 = new foo2();
foo3.printThis('test'); //print > test (as implemented in foo)
```

Comment: In my local example (which has more lines then what i provided), `input` is not being passed on to the newly created function anywhere in `index.html`. But  `foo2.printThis` has an output. How is `input` being passed on to it tho?

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, functions are like executable variables. The difference between referencing a function as a variable and executing the function is using `()`. When you did

```
foo2.printThis = function (input){
   console.log("done");
}
```

You *redefined* the function `printThis`. But when you did

```
foo2.printThis("hello");
```

You executed the function and printed to the console.

Comment: In my local example (which has more lines then what i provided), `input` is not being passed on to the newly created function anywhere in `index.html`. But  `foo2.printThis` has an output. How is `input` being passed on to it tho? that's my question.

Comment: When you leave out a parameter in JavaScript, it sets the value of the parameter to `undefined` and doesn't throw an error as long as that parameter is never used within the function. You redefined `foo2.printThis` so that the parameter is no longer actually used within the function, so that parameter becomes optional, and it will print `"done"` no matter what you pass to it. Does that help?

Comment: Ok assume the function does take in an input and instead of printing `"done"` in outputs the input. At that point where is the input coming from?

Comment: The input then would come from the parameter list next time you execute `printThis`. If you do `foo2.printThis("print me");`, then `input` would get set to `"print me"`.